# systemd: script execution on socket activity

Tags: bash, scripts, systemd

I am trying to make *.service* and *.socket* to listen any activity on a port and run a script if it happens.

for .service

```
[Unit]
Description=Sending Magic Packet to some PC

[Service]
After=exmaple.socket
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStart=/some/path/to/script/example.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=exmaple.service
```

and that part for *.socket:

```
[Unit]
Description=Sending Magic Packet to some PC

[Socket]
ListenStream=1234
MaxConnectionsPerSource=2
```

So a questions is how to start service ONLY at port activity and not try to restart service everytime then script finishes do its job?